# Specify font when performing OCR

Tags: images, ocr

I have a folder full of images that I need to convert to text.  Each one contains a string of numbers and spaces on a single line.  The images are computer-generated (i.e. not scans with extra artifacts).  The images are cropped so that it's just the numbers with about 4 pixels of padding all around.

I've tried each of the following:

```
tesseract temp.png stdout -psm 6
tesseract temp.png stdout -psm 6 nobatch digits
```

Neither recognizes the text with 100% accuracy.  The font places the 6 a little bit higher than the rest of the digits so that is likely contributing to the poor accuracy.

Since these images are computer-generated, each number looks exactly the same.  So is there a way I can take crops of each of these digits and feed them in to something so that when the OCR software (or really any sort of software) sees that exact shape it knows it's that number?